# Recycling SQLConnection in C# Code Multiple Times

Tags: c#, sql, connection

I need to learn something I have never quite grasped when needing to do multiple database reads in a short script. Basically, all that's changing is the SQL command, but I seem to fumble with exactly how to reuse connections and connectors. To make this simple I will give three SQL commands I need to execute and assign to int variables.

```
string Command1 = "";
string Command2 = "";
string Command3 = "";
int doorcount = 0;
int tirecount = 0;
int windowcount = 0;

Command1 = "SELECT DoorCount From Cars WHERE Car = 'Civic'";
Command2 = "SELECT TireCount FROM Vehicles WHERE VehicleType = 'Motorcycle'";
COmmand3 = "SELECT WindowCount FROM House WHERE HouseType = 'Ranch'";

string Connection_String = Properties.Settings.Default.Innovate_Loan_ServicingConnectionString.ToString();
            SqlConnection Conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String);
            SqlCommand Comm1 = new SqlCommand(Command1, Conn);
            Conn.Open();
            SqlDataReader DR1 = Comm1.ExecuteReader();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(DR1);
            Conn.Close();
       doorcount = dt.Rows[0]["DoorCount"];
```

At this point I need to do the second and third queries but how do I recycle the connection? What is the syntax so I don't have to keep recreating things?

Comment: recycling commands *effectively* when dealing with multiple connections is ... very complex; in most cases, it isn't necessary, though; frankly, I'd just use Dapper or similar, and let it worry about all that mess. Also: note that you may want to look into "parameters" - again, Dapper will help with that. Happy to post an example via Dapper, but frankly: I haven't written manual command/parameter creation **in application code** in years, for exactly this reason - it just isn't useful code for you to be messing with

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using a tool like Dapper (which is *designed* for folks who want to write their own SQL, but who don't want to be messing with the details of the ADO.NET API):

```cs
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Connection_String))
{
    conn.Open();
    doorCount = conn.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT DoorCount From Cars WHERE Car = 'Civic'");
    tirecount = conn.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT TireCount FROM Vehicles WHERE VehicleType = 'Motorcycle'");
    windowcount = conn.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT WindowCount FROM House WHERE HouseType = 'Ranch'");
}
```

There are also options for issuing all 3 operations in a single operation and consuming the results via a multi-grid reader, or for reading them as individual columns of a single row, etc. Or for adding parameters (if the literals like `'Civic'` are actually data inputs). As an example using parameters:

```cs
string car = "Civic"; // actually from input somewhere
// ...
doorCount = conn.QuerySingle<int>("SELECT DoorCount From Cars WHERE Car = @car",
    new { car } // named parameters expressed as an anonynmous type instance
);
```

Comment: Will Dapper take care of the potential SQL injection issue since the OP is passing the filter conditions directly? You might have indicated in your comment above...but I just wanted to double check

Comment: @Barns as I hinted: it will *if you use parameters*; I'll edit the body to show how

Comment: Thanks for the code, however, in this situation, I'm not allowed to use anything not out of the box. I know, get with the times. Looks cool. Too bad I can't use it.

Comment: @user3179585 then: there aren't any short-cuts except those that you write yourself

Comment: @MarcGravell Does Dapper do anything more than what `Connection pooling` does in ADO.NET? Or maybe Dapper benefit from MARS feature to fetch multi query faster?  Do you agree with what I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @Arman dapper deals with all the command / parameter / reader bits - so you don't have to. It isn't worth worrying about pooling when issuing 3 consecutive queries: just: issue them on the same managed connection instance. And MARS should almost always be avoided like the plague - a multi-grid command would be simpler